# Broken style in laravel email notification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, html-email

I send several line of list:

```
->line(' - Submit your own recipes and link to your own site.Get customized newsletters based on your food and drink profile.')
->line(' - Take part in contests with amazing prizes and get invited to events!')
->line(' - Are you a business or brand? Create your own profile to promote to your audience!')
```

But last item of list get broken styles:

[image]

How fix it?

[image: Email styles]

Comment: please, show more code

Comment: Inspect the last list item, there is probably a css selector targeting it.

Comment: @Sakezzz which code u want to see? Other things do laravel.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter i see it. I add screenshots. But how it fix?

Comment: @bunumu better would be the whole line

Answer (score 1):

Use below Code:

```
class HelloUser extends Notification {
            public function via($notifiable){
                return ['mail'];
            }

            public function toMail($notifiable) {
                return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('Submit your own recipes and link to your own site.Get customized newsletters based on your food and drink profile.')
                    ->line('Take part in contests with amazing prizes and get invited to events!')
                    ->line('Are you a business or brand? Create your own profile to promote to your audience!');
            }

        }
```

Comment: But how create list?

Comment: check this reference, you will get better idea: https://laraveldaily.com/mail-notifications-customize-templates/